# EmberJS loading view from controller not route

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In one route I render multiple outlets, and foreach outlet I load its content using the its controller with the `content` variable. I would like to show a loading view for each outlet, but don't know how to since there are no loading route for them (and so I can't just create an handlebar).

I have no issue displaying the loading view when my app starts, using a `loading` handlebar. But for my outlets I have no routes neither resources to it, so there is no loading route or loading template available when checking the Ember console.

I need to find a trick so I can, in my outlet, display a loading view while the `content` is being fetched.

Any idea?

The route where I'm inserting the outlet:

```
App.ProfileRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render(); // default behavior, renders the default template

        // loads documents outlet
        this.render('documents', {
            into: 'profile',
            outlet: 'documents',
            controller: 'documents'
        });

        // load other outlets after
    }
});
```

The associated handlebar:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="profile">
  <div id="profile-sections">
    {{outlet documents}}
    {{outlet accounts}}
    {{outlet contacts}}
  </div>
</script>
```

Controller:

```
App.DocumentsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    itemController: 'document',

    content: function () {
        return this.store.findAll('document');
    }.property()
});
```

Then, in the documents.hbs template I just loop over the documents, link them to the item controller, and have my logic. That's all. I've tried to add the `loading` function into the `actions` of the controller, but it didn't work (just logged some text but nothing showed up).

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

personally I'd add all those finds to the model hook, and use the default loading route.  Something like this (I guessed on the models for accounts and contacts).

```
App.ProfileRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      documents: this.store.find('document'),
      accounts: this.store.find('account'),
      contacts: this.store.find('contact')
    });
  }
});
```

Then in your template use `render`

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="profile">
  <div id="profile-sections">
    {{render 'documents' documents}}
    {{render 'accounts' accounts}}
    {{render 'contacts' contacts}}
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: It works great, thanks! The only downside is that I wanted to have a loading view for each of my sections (they are collapsible sections), and here it's one general, for documents, contact, etc. But I think that will be enough, just need to find the right message and a good UI when loading and that should be enough for now :)

Answer (score 0):

So I just want to add that I did a little bit different, so I can still keep my outlets, and not rendering view just like that. I have some needs that makes things kind of complicated, here my solution:

Route:

```
App.ProfileRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            accounts: this.store.findAll('account'),
            documents: this.store.findAll('document'),
            contacts: this.store.findAll('contact')
        });
    },

    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        this.controllerFor('accounts').set('model', model.accounts);
        this.controllerFor('documents').set('model', model.documents);
        this.controllerFor('contacts').set('model', model.contacts);
    },

    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render(); // default behavior, renders the default template

        // loads accounts outlet
        this.render('accounts', {
            into: 'profile',
            outlet: 'accounts',
            controller: 'accounts'
        });

        // loads documents outlet
        this.render('documents', {
            into: 'profile',
            outlet: 'documents',
            controller: 'documents'
        });

        // loads contacts outlet
        this.render('contacts', {
            into: 'profile',
            outlet: 'contacts',
            controller: 'contacts'
        });
    }
});
```

Then in the template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="profile">
  <div id="profile-sections">
    {{outlet documents}}
    {{outlet accounts}}
    {{outlet contacts}}
  </div>
</script>
```

And the easy loading handlebar:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="profile/loading">
  <div id="profile-loading">
    My loading spinner and text
  </div>
</script>
```

And it works perfect.